# Python - error in calling a function from a class

Tags: python, class, jupyter-notebook, python-class

I am trying to use a code that has been run successfully before by my colleagues.

But, when I try to replicate the situation I get an error.
Here is the situation:

Class and function defined as:

```
Class X:

   def f1(self, params)
   ...

   def f2(self, params)
   ...

Class Y(X):

   def f3(self, params..)

   ...

   def G(self, params):

   ... so on
```

All of these are saved under 'classes.py' file in the notebook.

So, from my jupyter notebook, I am trying to call the function G() as:

```
import classes

X.G(params)
```

Now I get an error like:

```
" name 'X' is not defined "
```

I also tried calling like: `Y.G(params)`
And get the similar error like name Y is not defined.
I believe, there is no error on the code, as it has been run before.

Can anyone explain what could possibly go wrong here.
Also, I do not understand the line definition of `Class Y(X)`.
My assumption, is Class Y is a sub class of main class X.
But, anyway, some insights are helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Why are you defining `f()` twice in `X`?

Comment: If you import classes then X is available as `classes.X`

Comment: Replace "X" by "classes.X" to solve this problem.

Comment: better practice is to go `from classes import X, Y`

Comment: @MattDMo f() should be f1(), f2() so on... I w ill try these methods.  Thanks

Comment: @SGotham Please [edit] your post accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
class X:
    def print_a(self):
        print('a')

    def print_b(self):
        print('b')

class Y(X):
    def print_a(self):
        print('overriden print a from class X')

instance = Y()
instance.print_a()
```

returns

> overriden print a from class X

When you inherit a class in another class you coul use a functionalty from the inherited class, add aditional functionalities, or even override functionalities.

EDIT:
Since you `import classes` your statement should look like

```
import classes
instance = classes.Y() #You should call a method from an instance of the class:
instance.G() #and the call the method:
```

[Python class inheritance.](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp)

Comment: @wwii Does now the answer cover your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `name X is not defined` errors because `X` has not been defined. It would be available if you used `from classes import X` or accessed it as `classes.X()`. Also, you typically want to name an instantiation of a class

```
foo = classes.X()
```

for example.